# How to access Woocommerce API with Flutter? Flutter & woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, flutter, woocommerce

I want to create a flutter app using the http package that connects to the woocommerce api, how can I use the package to connect?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to obtain the REST API from the woocommerce settings of your website, then connect it to you App

Comment: I suggest you can give move specific answer by provide the source, example for this case, it would be great if you can share the document of Woocommerce API https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/

Even better if you can share some of your work that you have done